# Receiving: "Route with name "imageAdd" not found" for defined route

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I am receiving this error in Zend3 for a route that is defined in my module.config.php file where my routes are defined.

Here is the link on my view file that is causing the error:

```
    <p>
        <a href="<?= $this->url('property/imageAdd', ['p_id' => $property->p_id]) ?>">Add Image</a>
    </p>
```

Here is my router set up:

```
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'property' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'     => '/property',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\ListController::class,
                        'action'        => 'forsale',
                    ],
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes'  => [

                    'detail' => [
                        'type' => Segment::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route'     => '/detail[/:p_id]',
                            'defaults'  => [
                                'action' => 'detail',
                            ],
                            'constraints' => [
                                'p_id'      => '[1-9]\d*',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                    'add' => [
                        'type' => Literal::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route'     => '/add',
                            'defaults'  => [
                                'controller'    => Controller\WriteController::class,
                                'action'        => 'add',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                    'imageAdd' => [
                        'type' => Segment::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route'     => '/imageAdd[/:p_id]',
                            'defaults'  => [
                                'controller'    => Controller\WriteController::class,
                                'action'        => 'imageAdd',
                            ],
                            'constraints' => [
                                'p_id'      => '[1-9]\d*',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],             
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Any help you can provide would be most appreciated, I look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply define your parent "property" route as a Literal type and not a Segment type. That should suffice to enable access to the child routes.